# Where in laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, laravel-5

I am trying to retrieve zipcodes from the database where I am getting an error- Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given. I am not sure if my where in query is correct. Thanks in advance.

$countiesList array looks like = ["Beaverhead", "Big Horn",......]

function in the model is:

```
public static function counties_zip($countiesList)
    {

        $zipCodes= Zip::select('ZIPCode')
                  ->distinct()
                  ->whereIn('CountyName', $countiesList)
                  ->orderBy('ZIPCode', 'asc')
                  ->get();
        return $zipCodes;
    }
```

In the controller:

```
public function zipCodes(Request $request) {


        $zipCodes = Zip::counties_zip($request->counties);


        return json_encode($zipCodes);

    }
```

and my jS:

```
$(".submit").on("click", function(){
        myList = [];
        $('.select2 option:selected').each(function() {
            myList.push($(this).val())
        });
        $countiesList=myList;


        console.log($countiesList);
        $.ajax({
                    type: "get",
                    url: http_host + '/leads/regions/counties/zipcodes?counties=' + $countiesList,
                    data: { counties: $countiesList},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var htmlText = '';
                        for ( var i=0;i<data.length;i++ ) {
                            htmlText += '<div class="div-conatiner">';
                            htmlText += '<input type="checkbox">' +  data[i].ZipCode;
                            htmlText += '<div>';
                        }
                        $(".main-div").append(htmlText);
                    }
                });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the javascript I used JSON.stringify to convert the javascript array to JSON array. Then in the model I decoded the JSON string using json_decode.
JS:

```
 $(".submit").on("click", function(){
            myList = [];
            $('.select2 option:selected').each(function() {
                myList.push($(this).val())
            });
            $countiesList=myList;


            console.log($countiesList);
            $.ajax({
                        type: "get",
                        url: http_host + '/leads/regions/counties/zipcodes?counties=' + $countiesList,
                        data: { counties: $countiesList},
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            var htmlText = '';
                            for ( var i=0;i<data.length;i++ ) {
                                htmlText += '<div class="div-conatiner">';
                                htmlText += '<input type="checkbox">' +  data[i].ZipCode;
                                htmlText += '<div>';
                            }
                            $(".main-div").append(htmlText);
                        }
                    });
        });
```

Model:

```
public static function counties_zip($countiesList)
    {
        $county= json_decode($countiesList, true); 
        $zipCodes= Zip::select('ZIPCode')
                  ->distinct()
                  ->whereIn('CountyName', $county)
                  ->orderBy('ZIPCode', 'asc')
                  ->get();
        return $zipCodes;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you're using a `GET` request to pass multiple `counties` values to your controller, but not using the right `counties[]` parameter in your request. Currently, if you were to do a `dd($countiesList);` in your function, you wouldn't get an array, as you're not passing it an array; your passing a single value.

To specify a parameter as an array in a `GET` request, you'd need to do:

```
/leads/regions/counties/zipcodes?counties[]=one&counties[]=two...
```

For every single `counties` value you're trying to filter down to.

You may want to look into structuring this as a `POST` request, as

```
data : {
  counties: $countieList
}
```

should be properly handled as an array of values in a `$.post(url, data, function(response){ ... });` or `$.ajax(...)` request.

Comment: Thank you Tim for your solution. I sticked to get and used JSON.stringify to convert the javascript array to JSON array. Then in the model I decoded the JSON string using json_decode.

Comment: No problem; glad you got it solved. Btw, feel free to accept your posted answer; the question will be marked as closed, which helps future visitors having a similar issue find a solution quicker. Cheers.